# Inset and Outset JavaFX Border Style

Tags: java, css, javafx, border

I am trying to make an XP styled minesweeper application using javaFX. The last thing i need is a way to get the sunken border effect. 
I tried using CSS but I had no luck.
I attached a image of the minesweeper border that I want, as well as a the border in CSS (which unfortunately didnt work with FX).
The only thing i couldnt generate was how the two colors come together at the corner. How they come together on a diagonal. 
Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: CSS generated]

[[image: Minesweeper sunken board]]